# Negating an image using a spatial filter

Tags: image-processing, multimedia

I was wondering if i could negate an image using a spatial filter, i know we could negate it using point operations but what about using a filter, is it possible ??
what matrix for a 3x3 should be used for example.

Comment: By "negating" do you mean taking the negative of an image? i.e. `out = 255 - in` if the image is unsigned 8-bit integer?  Another question is **why** do you want this in a filter?  Why aren't point operations sufficient?

Comment: yes i know but i need to know if it is possible or not for specific research i'm working on.

Comment: Well, as it's a point process, the value will be independent of the 8 neighbours so I there will have to be 8 zeroes in your 3x3 array. All that remains is whether you can contrive a central value, and any offset and/filter factor you may be permitted, to do the negation.

Comment: @MarkSetchell - You're certainly on to something, but I cannot see this being put in a spatial filter because essentially, the "weights" would change depending on what the pixel value is in the centre of the neighbourhood at any given time.  If I understand the OP correctly, they don't want an adaptive spatial filter, but a filter whose weights are static for each pixel neighbourhood that exists.

Comment: @user3600154 - I can't see this being done with a spatial filter as the filter weights would rely heavily on the input.  Usually with spatial filters, the weights are static and don't change.

Comment: @MarkSetchell that's what i reached actually, the 8 zeros, but i can't find a value for the center of the mask to negate, that's the problem actually?

Comment: @user3600154 - That's the problem.  The centre of the mask will change depending on what the centre pixel is for the neighbourhood.  I don't think it's possible to do this with spatial filters.

Comment: Essentially, you are trying to find "*a multiplication by `x`*" that is equivalent to a "*subtraction from 255*" in the range 0-255. That can't exist in my limited mathematical repertoire - although doubtless there is a "*Complex Plane Number Theorist*" out there who thinks differently :-)